# time difference between two rows - mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to know if there is any way where i can calculate time difference between two rows. I want to calculate time difference for name -> test etc. The name can be in any order.

I want to know if test has two times at row 1 and 3 and then at row 7 and 11, can i calculate time difference between these rows? i.e for row 1 and 3, and other for row 7 and 11.

below image with my database

[image]

Comment: If you load the values into PHP you can use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class, but there is surely a way to do it with sql as well

Comment: You can use TIMEDIFF for this http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timediff-function.php

Comment: don'use image but post text data sample ..

Comment: `TIMEDIFF()`  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: can you also define - *"i want to know if test has two times at row 1 and 3"* - and if that should also be "counting" how many times they appear? Your question is unclear in regards to that.

Comment: *"7 and 11"* - there is no rows up to those; what do you mean by that? foreseeing additional rows?

Comment: ^ those are questions and need to be answered. If you left the question, you may not see myself or others in the question presently (when you do return).

Comment: I still don't get it. my bad. The time is in single column for different user. what i want to know if there is any way where i can calculate time difference for same user for different time stamp.?

Comment: @ChiragPatel someone gave you an answer below. If it doesn't solve it and in regards to the comments I left, you will need to place a comment under the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try using [**TIMEDIFF()**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) and **subquery**

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF((SELECT `entered_at` FROM `demo_test3` WHERE `id`='1'),
               (SELECT `entered_at` FROM `demo_test3` WHERE `id`='3'))
```

Comment: I feel the question goes deeper than this. Read their question again and very carefully.

Comment: Please close the question. partially agree with @narayan reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the difference in PHP you can do something like this.

```
function secondsBetweenRows($first, $second)
{
    return strtotime($second->entered_at) - strtotime($first->entered_at);
}

// group rows by users
$users = []
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $users[$row->name] = $row;
}

// check row difference
$timeDiff = [];
foreach ($users as $userName => $userRows) {
    // assume there are always to, if not do some checks here
    $timeDiff[$userName] = secondsBetweenRows($userRows[1], $userRows[0]);
}

print_r($timeDiff);
/*
  Array
  (
      [test]  => 24
      [test1] => 26
  )
*/
```